# How is a non-UWP app in the Windows Store?

Tags: wpf, winapi, uwp

[This app](https://www.microsoft.com/store/apps/9nblggh51jpm) is an executable and not a UWP, yet you can install it right from the Windows Store. I've been looking for how to put the executable apps I've made to the Windows Store but couldn't find how. Can someone explain how to do this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is done by using the [Desktop Bridge](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/bridges/desktop), also known as the Desktop App Converter.

It allows you to bring an exe (win32, winforms, WPF, ...) to the Windows Store so people can install it on their Windows 10 machine through the (trusted) store instead of having it to download it from obscure download sites.

The first step is simply [using the Desktop App Converter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-root#convert) to get your .exe in the store. Once that is done, you can start adding Windows 10 specific features (like in-app purchases) to the converted app. Most simple .exe files and installers (msi, InstallShield, ...) can be converted easily, if you run into issues, don't hesitate to post on the [official forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windowsapps/en-us/home?forum=wpdevelop) to get feedback or help.

Comment: I use the app store to get the app but the app store be break.![](http://7xqpl8.com1.z0.glb.clouddn.com/%E9%97%AA%E9%80%80GleDitor.gif)